# Permutation of all elements in the list of lists

Tags: java, list, java-8, permutation

I have the List of Lists. For example it looks like:

```
List<List<Double>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

If I iterate it over all elements it looks for example like:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[1, 5, 10]
```

I want to find most efficient method in Java 8 which get me back all possible combinations with exactly **one** element from **every** `List<Double>`  or with another words the permutation of all elements from the different lists. If is it possible without big quantity of for loops. For example:

```
[1, 4, 1]
[1, 4, 5]
[1, 4, 10]
[1, 5, 1]
....
```